# Avoid using "mutable" variable to call a method with a byref (out in C#) parameter?

Tags: f#, pass-by-reference, c#-to-f#, f#-3.0

So I have this class in C#:

```
public class Foo : IFoo {
    public bool TryConnect(out Status status) {
        ...
    }
}
```

And I want to consume it with F#.

Unfortunately I had to use some hackery such as:

```
type FooService (foo : IFoo) =

    member x.Execute() =
        let mutable status = Unchecked.defaultof< ^Status>
        foo.TryConnect(&status) |> ignore
        (...do something with status...)
```

Is there a way to not use "mutable" here? In the end, I'm not actually using the first initialization value at all.

(I'm using F# 2.0, but if you have hints that only apply to F# 3.0, I'll be happy to hear them.)

Thanks

Comment: is `let status=MyFoo.TryConnect` not working?

Comment: TryConnect returns bool, not Status type

Comment: sorry, I meant what @Daniel says in his answer below...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`out` params are automatically tuplized. So, you can do:

```
let res, status = foo.TryConnect()
```

For more info, see [Passing by Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233213.aspx) on MSDN.